# Javascript - Function works once, but never again

Tags: javascript

I'm building a very simple lightbox script; when you click a button, the lightbox is created. When you click on the lightbox background, it is removed.

The first time you call the function it works just fine. Click button, lightbox shows, click lightbox, it disappears. However, if you try to click the button AGAIN, nothing happens - the div isn't called. No console errors or anything, don't know what the problem is.

**JSFIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/3fgTC/

**CODE**

```
function closeLightBox(){
        document.body.removeChild(lightBox);
}

function createElem(){
    var elem = "<div id='lightBox'></div>";
    var bodyElem = document.body;
        bodyElem.innerHTML = elem + bodyElem.innerHTML;
    var lightBox = document.getElementById("lightBox");
        lightBox.style.width = "100%";
        lightBox.style.height = "800px";
        lightBox.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,.5)";
        lightBox.onclick = function(){
            closeLightBox();
        }
}
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
    for (var i = 0; i<button.length; i++){
        button[i].onclick = function(){
            createElem();
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't prepend to `innerHTML`; that makes the browser re-parse the HTML and re-create every DOM element, losing event handlers in the process. Instead, use `document.createElement`:

```
var lightBox = document.createElement('div');
document.body.insertBefore(lightBox, document.body.firstChild);
```

Furthermore, inline `closeLightBox`:

```
lightBox.onclick = function() {
    document.body.removeChild(lightBox);
}
```

**[Try it.](http://jsfiddle.net/LxmZK/)**

Comment: Ah, hadn't heard of `createElement` before (new to JS). Just looking over the docs, pretty simple and makes a lot of sense. Thanks! Is the inline `closeLightBox` just for making the code simpler, or is it actually causing problems in some way?

Comment: @Jascination: Well, before, you were using `lightBox` in `closeLightBox`. `lightBox` is the name of a variable declared in `createElem`, so it is inaccessible in `closeLightBox`. It just happened to work for you since the `id` of the `div` is also `lightBox`, but I stopped giving it an `id` in my example, so it has to be inlined so the variable is still accessible.

Comment: Got it. Cheers for the help mate.